# error generating separate pdf from pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I followed the chapter 7pgfplots manual (Revision 1.8) to generate seperate pdf files from the  pgfplots   figure I could not get the required pdf files.
MY file name is test.tex

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage {tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\pgfrealjobname{test}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,fill=blue!20,rounded corners= 2pt,  rectangle, minimum    height= 2em, minimum width =4em,line width =1.5pt,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=gray!15, circle,radius = 1.5cm, node distance=1cm,line width =1.5pt,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, color=black!50, -latex']

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{document}
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{f1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
% We start by placing the blocks,input output, branch

\node [input, name=input,label=left:$\phi_{des}$] {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum1) {};

\node [block, right of=sum1,node distance=2cm] (controller1) {$K_{p}$};
\path (sum1)--coordinate(branch1) (controller1);
\node [block, above of=controller1,node distance=1.5cm] (controller2) {$K_{i}\int e\,dt $};
\node [sum, right of=controller1,node distance=1.5cm] (sum2) {};
\node [block, right of=sum2  ] (system) {${1\over{J_xs^2}}$};
\node [block, below of=system,node distance=1.5cm 
        ] (controller3) {$K_{d}s$};
\node [input, right of= controller3, node distance = 1.35cm](y_mid){};

% We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
% calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 

\draw [->,line width =1pt] (sum2) -- node[name=u] {$\tau_{\phi}$} (system);
\node [output, right of=system,node distance =2cm] (output) {};
\path (system)--coordinate(branch2)(output);    %Finds the coordinate between system 
\path (branch2)|- coordinate(branch3)(controller3);    %Finds the coordinate between 

\node[input,name= feedback,below of= sum2,node distance=2.5cm]{};
% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 

\draw [draw,->,line width =1pt] (input) -- node[pos =0.9] {$+$} (sum1);
\draw [->,line width =1pt] (sum1) -- node[pos =0.1]{$e$} (controller1);

\draw [->,line width =1pt] (branch1)node[branch]{} |-  (controller2);
\draw[->,line width =1pt](controller2)-|node[pos =0.95]{$+$} (sum2);

\draw [->,line width =1pt] (controller1) -- node [pos =0.9]{$+$} (sum2);

\draw [->,line width =1pt] (system) -- node[name =y]  {$\phi$}(output);
\draw[line width =1pt](branch2)node[branch]{}|- (controller3);

\draw [line width =1pt] (branch3) |-  (feedback);

\draw [->,line width =1pt] (controller3) -| node[pos=0.95]{$-$}(sum2);
\draw [->,line width =1pt] (feedback) -| node[pos=0.97]{$-$}(sum1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\endpgfgraphicnamed
\end{document}
```

I command  "pdflatex" first and then  "pdflatex --jobname f1 test"

> test.tex
>
> Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
>
> —
> 30
> Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over; \frac or \genfrac should be used instead >on input line 30.

Comment: Your example code doesn't use PGFPlots at all (even though you load it). Could you clarify the connection to PGFPlots? Also, why are you using the "manual" externalization method, instead of just using the `external` library?

Comment: If you uncomment the lines 5-6 the code works without any problems.

Comment: Your example runs fine here, if the correct file name is given in `\beginpgfgraphicnamed{<document filename.tex>}`.

Comment: @Jake My apologies for saying it pgfplots, and I had also tried automatic externalization it  did not create separate pdf files for figure.

Comment: @user28218: Maybe it would be more productive if you posted a question describing your problems with the automatic externalization, instead of trying to debug the manual way?

Comment: @user28218 my objectives was to generate separate pdf files for figure.

Comment: @Alexander does it produce separate files for figure ?

Comment: This definitely runs without problems on a current MiKTeX 2.9 with TikZ CVS. I copied your example, ran `pdflatex test.tex`, then `pdflatex --jobname f1 test` and get the compiled document and a separate figure.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander , it worked, previously I was not trying the stuff in command line.